# CalendR Package : Error in text != "" && is.null(text.pos) : 'length = 31' in coercion to 'logical(1)'

Tags: r

https://breatheaccra.org/historical-data/dist-0014/dev:864475046524632/August/HIS0A1KE1C
The calendR image in the link above is the output expected from the code.
The code below used to work before I changed my work computer. The code is supposed to display a calendar heatmap with PM2.5 values being displayed on its corresponding month. However, this is no longer the case I keep getting an error message. The length of the values in each column are all equal.

```
calendR(
  year = 2023,
  month = 7,
  months.col = "black",
  special.days = data3$Average,
  special.col = "#B60000",
  gradient = TRUE, 
  low.col = "#FFA8A8",
  text = paste(data3$PM2.5), 
  text.pos = as.numeric(format(data3$When, "%d")),
  text.col = "white",
  bg.img = img,
  orientation = "l",
  col = "white",
  lty = 0,
  weeknames = c("Mo", "Tu",  "We", "Th", "Fr", "Sa", "Su"),
  title = "Daily Average Particulate Matter (PM)2.5 recordings - Atomic Junction Taxi Rank",
  subtitle = "July 2023",
  subtitle.size = "16",
  subtitle.col = "red",
  day.size = 4
)



Error in text != "" && is.null(text.pos) : 
  'length = 31' in coercion to 'logical(1)'
```

```
text_labels <- as.character(data3$PM2.5)

month <- 7
year <- 2023
#text_labels has the same length as the number of days in the month


days_in_month <- as.numeric(format(as.Date(paste(year, month, 1, sep = "-")), "%d"))
text_labels <- head(text_labels, days_in_month)

calendR(
  start_date = 2023-07-01,
  end_date = 2023-07-30,
  months.col = "black",
  special.days = data3$Average,
  special.col = "#B60000",
  gradient = TRUE,
  low.col = "#FFA8A8",
  text = text_labels,
  text.pos = days_in_month,
  text.col = "white",
  orientation = "l",
  col = "white",
  lty = 0,
  weeknames = c("Mo", "Tu", "We", "Th", "Fr", "Sa", "Su"),
  title = "Daily Average Particulate Matter (PM) 2.5 Recordings - Atomic Junction",
  day.size = 4
)
```

I tried the above code and i had an error

```
Error in seq.int(0, to0 - from, by) : wrong sign in 'by' argument
```

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: @MrFlick I have modified the question and added a link to the output expected from the code before the I started getting the error message